# Whats the maximum timeout on GCP Workflows?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-workflows

I am trying to invoke cloud run endpoint using GCP Workflows. Even though cloud run has a maximum timeout of 1 hour, workflows is giving me error like

> Request timeout was 2500s, max allowed timeout is 1800s

Is this specific to workflows?
Couldn't find this in the documentation, Can anyone please confirm this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is documented on the `http.xxxx` functions https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/stdlib/http/get

```
timeout   float
```

> The request timeout, in seconds (default: 300.0). If the request takes
> longer than the timeout, a TimeoutError is raised. The maximum allowed
> timeout is 1800 seconds.